# Gmail REST API get message function returns invalid historyId

Tags: gmail-api

It seems like there may be a serious issue in the Gmail REST API.

1. Call /userId/messages to obtain a list of message
2. For each, call /userId/messages/id to get the message
3. Obtain the highest (or any) startHistoryId on each message object
4. Then call /userId/history/list passing startHistoryId as a parameter

The result is unexpected. The Gmail REST API is returning 404 Not Found.. It seems the returned historyId is not registered or valid.

On calling /userId/profile, the startHistoryId is valid and can be used successfully in the /userId/history/list call.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
"code" : 404,
"errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "global",
     "message" : "Not Found",
     "reason" : "notFound"
    } ],
  "message" : "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: Is this because Gmail creates a historyId for a message only at the point when a message is created? If the message was created along time ago, the history reference is deleted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug in the API and is documented at
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

Specifically "History IDs increase chronologically but are not contiguous with random gaps in between valid IDs. Supplying an invalid or out of date startHistoryId typically returns an HTTP 404 error code. A historyId is typically valid for at least a week, but in some circumstances may be valid for only a few hours. If you receive an HTTP 404 error response, your application should perform a full sync."

So you are likely just using a historyId that is outside the range of history stored (it's not stored indefinitely, that would be very expensive).  It's only stored long enough for syncing clients to need it (e.g. a week or so).

If you just need to sync from a certain point forward then just use the historyId returned from getProfile.  The historyId on a message was when the message was last updated, which could be months or years ago, longer than history is stored.

See also the sync'ing guide:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync

Comment: This is what I was looking for, however I'm running into a strange issue that maybe you can shed some light on. The user has nothing in messages.list {resultsSizeEstimate:0}. So I grab the historyId from getProfile to do a partial sync. However, when I try to pull history.list using the startHistoryId, it returns 404. What does this mean about the state of this mailbox? Is the most current startHistoryId just also out of date, indicating the mailbox has not been used in a very long time?