# Gmail API: users.history.list returns "Not Found" when using pageToken

Tags: gmail-api

For one of our users (and only one) we frequently get a "404 Not Found" error when calling `gmail.users.history.list`. Specifically, it happens when we're paging through the responses (i.e. a `pageToken` is given) from `gmail.users.history.list`.

The `list` method is called when a Gmail push notification indicates the user has a new `hisotryId`, at which point we use their *previous* history ID to get all changes up until this point. The first call to `list` always succeeds, but then when using the given `pageToken` provided from that initial response, the call fails.

What's weird is when we see these failures in the logs and then try the same call on our own manually later on, they work just fine.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you also supplying the `hisotryId` on the second call when you supply the `pageToken`?

Comment: @Tholle yes I am. I'm using the same history ID from the initial call. I believe this is the correct way to use it, and it seems to work for most other `history.list` calls outside of this user

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the same history ID from your initial call, it could be that you're using an invalid history ID. As mentioned in [`Users.history: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list),

> A `historyId` is typically valid for at least a week, but in some rare circumstances may be valid for only a few hours.

Try doing a [full synchronization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync#full_synchronization) as suggested,

> If you receive an HTTP 404 error response, your application should perform a full sync.

You may want to see this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801366/gmail-rest-api-get-message-function-returns-invalid-historyid) for additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this can also happen if your `startHistoryId` is too old and has expired out of Gmail's internal notifications queue.

---

This happened in development for me when I needed to test this feature after a long time, but had not updated any of the local history-IDs. In contrast, all of our production and staging environments were behaving well.