# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError 404 gmail api

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api

I'm fetching a message to get the full message through gmail API:

```
   Message msgfull = _gmailService.Users.Messages.Get("me", msg.Id).Execute();
```

I'm passing a valid msg.Id

> Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>
> Not Found [404]
>
> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Not Found [404] Errors [
>     Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global] ]

There is also this question [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/578)

Did someone encountered this?

Comment: Does this occur for any valid `msg.Id` or just to a specific one?

Comment: only for specific ones

Comment: Are you seeing a pattern to which files it occurs (e.g. are these files actual files uploaded to the Drive or just Google Docs/Sheets)?

Comment: If you search in Gmail web for:
msgid:0x<MessageIdFromGmailApi> do you see anything?

Comment: @TalAvissar I am seeing this too - using a messageID returned from the API

Comment: @TalAvissar & SOS I started seeing this yesterday - here's a link to my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656324/gmail-api-history-request-returning-invalid-ids-for-messages-added

Comment: @TalAvissar I even got back the same email with 2 message IDs - and now one doesn't even exist anymore. My tool was running the same time I sent an email, could be first it got a draft that's no longer a draft but was when it ran. Something funky with this API

Comment: It does not happen on all messages, but still, it's annoying with no answer from Google side.

Comment: No - did not happen with all message IDs - but with plenty of them - The thing is, I don't see actual messages in my gmail that I can't get. I think it's returning more than my actual messages

Comment: @MikeTurner & TalAvissar - I thought there was a problem with my code requests - so I tried it in the API explorer too... and that too gives me some invalid ids

Comment: @TalAvissar Any progress here?

Comment: @MikeTurner - attached my answer below

Answer (score 1):

This is "by design" and according to the documentation History IDs increase chronologically **but are not contiguous with random gaps** in between valid IDs.

> This is not a bug in the API and is documented at 
>   https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801366/gmail-rest-api-get-message-function-returns-invalid-historyid)

So, If you are performing the following steps:

1. fetching in the first step the historyIds through the history API (**along with their messages ids**) in these messages originated before 7 days then the history results may contain out of sync including the attached message ids and the history ids.
2. And then trying to use the message ids from the history fetch.

A possible solution is to fetch message ids of messages only by calling users.messages.list("me") **and not by relying on history queries**.

Anyhow, this looks like a bug on Google API side that causes users to not able to rely on history results older that are older than 1 week in the past.

> More info: Returns history records after the specified startHistoryId.
>   The supplied startHistoryId should be obtained from the historyId of a
>   message, thread, or previous list response. History IDs increase
>   chronologically but are not contiguous with random gaps in between
>   valid IDs. Supplying an invalid or out of date startHistoryId
>   typically returns an HTTP 404 error code. A historyId is typically
>   valid for at least a week, but in some rare circumstances may be valid
>   for only a few hours. If you receive an HTTP 404 error response, your
>   application should perform a full sync. If you receive no
>   nextPageToken in the response, there are no updates to retrieve and
>   you can store the returned historyId for a future request.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. I wish the Google team would finally pipe up. You are suggesting to always do a full sync instead of a partial sync? Does not sound like the right way. I understand there are random gaps, but that should not affect me. I'm not incrementing IDs and trying to fetch like that. I'm getting ids and fetching messages by those... these should not return 404 bec of a gap.

Comment: Also - it says that historyID is only valid for a week, not message IDs, if my history request goes through, all message ids returned should be valid.

Comment: if the historyId is older than one week and let's say the history id is not valid - how can the messageId which is attached to it be valid? a valid id that is connected to an invalid history id?

Comment: If the historyID is older than a week an invalid - it should not be returning invalid ids - it should error out with a 404. A history request returning invalid IDs does not seem to make sense and is not according to docs

Comment: And happens to be I used a historyID that was retrieved same day.. but thats besides the point. Answer does not make sense to me